# Fixed-Effects Regression with Panel Data - Dummy variable is excluded in Output

Tags: rstudio, linear-regression, dummy-variable, panel-data

I'm rather new to statistics and R. I'm currently working on a paper and I'm really stuck with a coding problem right now. I suspect that the problem lays within my dummy variable.

I did a fixed-effects regression with my panel data which worked out fine. All my variables (the Y and the Xs) were numeric. I decided to add another variable that is a dummy variable with two levels (yes/no).
I set the variable as as factor variable but whenever I try to run the regression it does not show up in the output. As soon as I remove one specific numeric variable - it shows up in the output.
I obviously don't want to exclude that one numeric variable to include my dummy variable - there must be another way or something I did wrong...

```
regdata <- read_excel("LinRegData.xlsx")
regdata$eu <- as.factor(regdata$eu)
attach(regdata)
pdata <- pdata.frame(regdata, index=c("country","year"))
pdata$eu <-as.factor((pdata$eu))


plmwithin <- plm(subaus ~ employ + pref + + iEaeM + eu, data = pdata, model="within", family = poisson,  effect = 'twoways', index = c('country', 'year'))
```

### The output always excludes the eu-variable:

```
Call:
plm(formula = subaus ~ employ + pref + eu + iEaeM, data = pdata, 
    effect = "twoways", model = "within", index = c("country", 
        "year"), family = poisson)

Unbalanced Panel: n = 32, T = 8-11, N = 288

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.4828507 -0.0867719 -0.0021724  0.0857117  0.7668712 

Coefficients:
          Estimate  Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)    
employ  0.03496136  0.00590717  5.9185  1.1e-08 ***
pref   -0.02081850  0.00908030 -2.2927  0.02272 *  
iEaeM  -0.00010028  0.00070435 -0.1424  0.88690    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Total Sum of Squares:    9.4599
Residual Sum of Squares: 8.183
R-Squared:      0.13498
Adj. R-Squared: -0.021654
F-statistic: 12.639 on 3 and 243 DF, p-value: 1.0498e-07
>
```

### If I exclude the iEaeM variable it shows:

```
Call:
plm(formula = subaus ~ employ + pref + eu, data = pdata, effect = "twoways", 
    model = "within", index = c("country", "year"), family = poisson)

Unbalanced Panel: n = 32, T = 8-23, N = 659

Residuals:
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-1.04463 -0.18859 -0.01558  0.14696  1.46631 

Coefficients:
          Estimate  Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)    
employ  0.01346798  0.00525102  2.5648  0.01056 *  
pref   -0.00014268  0.00927955 -0.0154  0.98774    
eu1    -0.27793656  0.06324072 -4.3949 1.31e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Total Sum of Squares:    64.478
Residual Sum of Squares: 61.197
R-Squared:      0.050889
Adj. R-Squared: -0.037401
F-statistic: 10.7592 on 3 and 602 DF, p-value: 6.7744e-07
>
```

Comment: What is eu? EU membership? Is there any variation at all? Dummies that do not have within-variation (like gender for people) are dropped by FE estimation.

Comment: Hello Marco - thanks for your reply. Yes it is the eu membership. The random effects model would also consider country and year as relevant if I understood correctly so that’s not an option. Is there any other way I could include the eu variable?

Comment: What I've seen once, to include a non-variation-dummy in  a fixed effects regression is to interact it with some variable. For example, `plm(formula = subaus ~ employ*eu + pref + iEaeM, data = pdata, effect = "twoways", model = "within", index = c("country", "year"), family = poisson)` It may answer the question: What is the effect of employment in a EU-member state?, What does `iEaeM` stand for?